# Progressive bar does not show progress

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason the progress bar is not working.

Here is the HTML, CSS, and JS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="nui://game/ui/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="bar-one bar-con">
        <div class="bar" data-percent="20"></div>
    </div>

  <div class="bar-two bar-con">
    <div class="bar" data-percent="50"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="bar-three bar-con">
    <div class="bar" data-percent="70"></div>
  </div>
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The rest of the code is in the link, I am still learning to use the page (thousand apologies):

https://jsfiddle.net/b4kqt1cz/

Comment: Is the code in the JavaScript block in your JS Fiddle included in `js/app.js`? If so, the question should be edited to include this, so that we have a [mcve] of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that jQuery is not being loaded, and as such the call to `$.fn.progress()` - where the progress bars are actually updated - is not working. This can be verified in your browser's console (usually found by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>), where you can find the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>      at window.onload

If possible, you should update your reference to jQuery in your `<head>` by either using one of the [jQuery CDN](https://code.jquery.com/) links, or downloading a copy of jQuery, placing it in your `js` folder and referencing it from there.

An updated [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4kqt1cz/3/), which changes the reference to JQuery to the CDN link for version 1.12.4, works as expected.

Comment: Also unrelated to your issue, but you're referencing `app.js` twice :)